# Red wire in logisim

Tags: logisim

[image]

I have  been messing around with logisim and I am fairly new and I cant figure out why I am  getting this red wire. 
In the picture is my memory which is currently reading from the top left cell and should be reading 1000000 but the wire turns red.I have  disconnected it from the other wires in the memory and the output worked so its just happening when its linked to the reads of the other cells.
 Does      anyone know why this could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

A red wire indicates an error value (a bit like X in VHDL). You haven't included enough of the design to show what's driving the wire, but make sure you have only one driver for that wire. Of course, if the driver for that wire also has a red input, you need to trace backwards to find the original error (errors propagate through components).

Comment: I don't know how to zoom out to take a better screen shot but the only error is occurring when any of the memory cells are trying to read and everything before then works fine