# Logisim Combinational circuit

Tags: logisim

[image]

Can someone please tell me why I am getting E for an output?

Comment: Sorry, not an answer but an observation: it seems you are decoding 10 of 16 combinations. Why not decode the unused 6 and invert the output? Saves gates.

Comment: In logisim, the red wires indicate an error -- see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/209112/red-wire-in-logisim -- see also http://www.cburch.com/logisim/docs/2.3.0/guide/bundles/colors.html -- looks like the problem originates from the inverters in the upper left corner. If you disconnect everything from an inverter's output, do you still get (e) red error? If there were multiple outputs wired together that would definitely be an error, but from the screenshot alone I don't see it.

Comment: Actually even the blue wires driven by the constant [0] are wrong (unknown signal value), the value should be known 0 (dark green wire color). Something's wrong at a more fundamental level. Try wiring up just a single inverter, driven by constant 0, and see if logisim will admit that the output is 1. It might be missing a tie-dot connection at the edge of the [0] box?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because your inverters aren't connected to the wires, red wire means an open circuit or an error in the connection.
Just make sure it's connected and it should work.

Comment: Yes. I noticed it too. OP didn't connect the wires to the input properly.

Answer (score 0):

The output on the right shows "error" because at least one input of the gate feading it is erroneous, too. This is true for other gates in your circuit also.

Most probably this happened (you didn't tell us):

While editing, you made some error that led to wires carrying "error", shown in red with the value `E`. Perhaps the simulation even stopped, and it might have told you.

To recover, reset the simulation, starting it again. You will find the commands in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

The wires are definitely not connected to the input blocks.
[image]